# Pandas - Setting new column - ["from-to"] - finding the first and last Date Time appearance

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that those columns are already in place - ["time","startTime","endTime","source"]   and I also have more columns that are not related for this question in this df.
I want to set up new Column that find the first appearance of an instance with the same startTime , endTime and Source and the last appearance of another instance with those values.
I want that every instance with those values will be added another field in a new Colum [from (first date)- to (last date)].
I do it in brute force to show the idea but obviously that take way too much time, is there any idea how to do it in pandas way?
the code:

```
    f["from-to"] = " "
    for i in df.index:
        minDate = df["time"][i]
        maxDate = df["time"][i]
        for j in df.index:
            if df["startTime"][i] == df["startTime"][j]:
                if df["endTime"][i] == df["endTime"][j]:
                    if df["source"][i] == df["source"][j]:
                                if minDate > df["time"][j]:
                                    minDate = df["time"][j]
                                elif maxDate < df["time"][j]:
                                    maxDate = df["time"][j]
        df["from-to"][i] = "from %s to %s" % (minDate,maxDate)
```

here is a example of the input (after export DF into CSV):
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXDG2.png)
here is a example of the desired output (after export DF into CSV):
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fJHE.png)

Comment: Can you provide example input and desired output? If former is big then please provide subset of it.

Comment: Something like `.groupby()[''].first()` wouldn't work? Could you provide some sample data and expected output to make sure the approach is fine?

Comment: sure , just added an example of the input and the desired output. (see edit post), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Groupby** source,endTime,startTime to account for all possible combinations.
2. **Sorting** can be done first,since groupby maintains order.
3. [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) is used since an additional column was requested, a simple aggregation function won't suffice.
4. Finally, a simple concatenation wraps the results into a single column with the required prefixes.

It is worth noting that the new "from-to" column is of type object rather than string.

```
def transform_gb_input(gb_input, prefix, agg_func) -> str:
    agg_col = gb_input.transform(agg_func).squeeze() #3
    return f"{prefix} " + agg_col.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

input_sorted_gb = input_df.sort_values(['time']).groupby(['startTime', 'endTime','source']) #1 + 2
input_df['from-to'] = transform_gb_input(input_sorted_gb, 'from', 'first') + ' - ' + transform_gb_input(input_sorted_gb,'to', 'last') #4
```